# Do metal skewers make a considerable different cooking time than wooden?

Tags: grilling, kebab

When making kebabs I usually use the metal re-usable skewers. However do they differ at all than their wooden counterparts? Dishes are fun to do but only if the meal is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely!  Metal skewers contribute to cooking the meat from the center as they pick up heat from the exposed parts and conduct it throughout.

It is a good idea not to crowd your metal skewers with pieces of food to promote this.  Not crowding the skewers also exposes more surface area for the food to caramelize.  Doing this on a wooden skewer runs the risk of burning the skewers and losing food into the grill.